# Prawn: anchor middle of the text to the given point

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

Prawn has [`height_of_formatted`](http://prawnpdf.org/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Text.html#method-i-height_of) method to determine, well, height of formatted text, so its top left coordinate could be calculated when one needs to vertically align the middle of it to some anchor.

But there is no `width_of_formatted` method.

I'm drawing graph, and I need the text (dot label) to be centered right above some point (dot itself). So I know that middle of the text has x-coordinate of the dot.

How do I get x-coordinate of the beginning of the text (so I could provide it to `draw_text` and other rendering methods)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `bounding_box` instead of `draw_text` you can specify the width of the bounding box for the text. Then if you centre-align the text you should be able to specify the exact x-coordinate of the middle. (it's the x-position of the box plus half the width)

Let's say you had a point at x-coordinate 72 and you want to put the label "hello world!" so the centre of the word is the same x-coordinate. You don't know how wide the word "hello" is but you're sure it'll fit inside a box of width 500.

72 - (500/2) = -178

```
bounding_box([-178, 100], :width => 500) do
  text "hello world!", align => :center
end
```

Comment: You could make the width of the text_box as wide as the page if you like. The text will be centred in it and the rest of the box wont show. I'll put an example in the answer